# Is it possible to use Box on the command line, like Git?

Tags: git

We started using Box for version control and backing up our sketch files, but the constant dragging files into folders is not fun. We also use Git for our dev work, and love the command line commits, push, pull, rollbacks etc.

Is there a way to integrate Box with the command line? All of us use Macs, by the way.

Comment: Perhaps [Github LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) is something for you. It supports versioning of large files (I have no idea how large sketch files are)

Answer (score 0):

Box has an [API](https://docs.box.com/docs/) which you could use with curl from the command line. [Their GitHub page](https://github.com/box) also has APIs that can be used with programming languages, e.g. Python.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be as simple as linux cp/mv command? What are you looking for? The ability to revert and manage unchecked out items?

pybox - 
https://github.com/hzheng/pybox may serve the functions you are looking. It is "a Python API/client that manipulates files on box.com (a.k.a box.net)"